# Stream files generated on request in memory

Tags: node.js, node-streams

I have a loop where I generate files (around 500KB each) and if there is too much data Node throws out of memory error (no wonder, it's around 4GB of data). I read about streams and I'm trying to understand how can I incorporate it in my app.

Most of the information I find is about streaming file that is already on the disk. What I want to do is to create files on the fly (which I already do), send one by one (or however chunks work) as they are generated and hand it to the client in a zip when it's done (so it's easy on the RAM).

I don't ask for specific code - more about where to look so I can read about it.

Comment: you can start with looking at substack or dominc-tarr's work - they have a lot of libraries that support streams - otherwise going through node-school's stream-adventure is quite useful

Comment: @DenisTsoi so what I'm looking for is out of typical Node streams scope?

Comment: what do you mean out of scope?

Comment: node streams are baked into Node core - however, teh interface for say, fetching a remote file can be used via say `requests` or `request-stream` -

Comment: @DenisTsoi I mean I can't easily achieve it without additional modules. Just read about Node School - will definitely take a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: you CAN do it within node core - however its somewhat redundant if you try to solve it by reinventing the wheel.

the only thing is say you use - `node-fetch` - there's already a stream interface in that lib. You can pipe the result of the request into gzip and whatever transform/writeable stream you want.

Comment: I just found that `stream` is not or barely supported on the client-side (front end) so I need to figure something else now. Thanks though!

Comment: request-stream can be browserified into the client-side - alternatively you can use either websockets or ArrayBuffers to parse the incoming stream